# Best Maven FOP plugin?

Tags: maven, apache-fop

I need to transform some xml into html and pdf formats as part of a maven build and am just wondering what plugins people are using out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [fop-maven-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/fop-maven-plugin/)?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if your starting XML is docbook format or not but there is a fairly decent maven plugin called docbkx-maven-plugin. It will give you lots of control over the process of conversion.

Here is the dependency:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.agilejava.docbkx</groupId>
    <artifactId>docbkx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.13</version>
</plugin>
```

Plugin website: http://mojo.codehaus.org/docbook-maven-plugin/introduction.html

Plugin tutorial: http://mojo.codehaus.org/docbook-maven-plugin/introduction.html